# JSON, how to stack several data classes into one single json array

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I am quite new to Android with Kotlin and even more newer to JSON. I am following an example without success. It is frustrating because I am sure there is way easier to what I am trying to do.

Note that, each position in the array below contains one type (or data class), like "speed", "rpm", etc.

```
[
  {
    "variable": "speed",
    "value": 35,
    "unit": "mhp"
  },
  {
    "variable": "rpm",
    "value": 2190
  },
  {
    "variable": "fuel",
    "value": 97,
    "unit": "%"
  },
  {
    "variable": "location_car",
    "value": "car",
    "location": {
      "lat": -23.550556,
      "lng": -46.633146
    }
  },
  {
    "variable": "gear",
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "variable": "brake",
    "value": false
  }
]
```

**EDIT1 - Inserted the code showing my solution; note it does not cover the adding of the location coordinates within location**

What is the more Android with Kotlin way using GSon to build the JSon array above? Please, only answers with Android Kotlin with Gson library.

```
        val speed = JSONObject()
        speed.accumulate("variable", "speed")
        speed.accumulate("value", "35")
        speed.accumulate("unit", "mph")

        val rpm = JSONObject()
        rpm.accumulate("variable","rpm")
        rpm.accumulate("value","2190")

        val fuel = JSONObject()
        fuel.accumulate("variable", "fuel")
        fuel.accumulate("value", 97)
        fuel.accumulate("unit", "%")

        val location_info = JSONObject()
        location_info.accumulate("variable", "location_car")
        location_info.accumulate("value", "car")

        val location_coord = JSONObject()
        location_coord.accumulate("lat", -23.550556)
        location_coord.accumulate("lng", -46.633146)

        val gear = JSONObject()
        gear.accumulate("variable", "gear")
        gear.accumulate("value", "2")

        val brake = JSONObject()
        brake.accumulate("variable", "brake")
        brake.accumulate("value", false)
        
        val sensorAllDataArray = JSONArray()
        sensorAllDataArray.put(speed)
        sensorAllDataArray.put(rpm)
        sensorAllDataArray.put(fuel)
        sensorAllDataArray.put(location_info)
        sensorAllDataArray.put(gear)
        sensorAllDataArray.put(brake)

        println("$sensorAllDataArray")
```

Comment: It would likely work better if you shared the code you have so far and asked the community to help you fix it, rather than asking for a ready made solution that just works.

Comment: I was planning to let it wide open to have a better solution than mine; I just inserted the code;

Comment: Have you tried converting the code you attached into Gson on your own? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I need that formatted string to post it in the body of a request. I tried but did not find how. I am struggling now on that " coordinate structure" within the location.

Comment: Using JSON arrays in such a case makes less sense than using JSON objects like `{"speed":{...},"rpm":{...},...}`. If you still think that using arrays is a must and the service you're trying to adapt to cannot be changed, consider using `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` from Gson extras directory (right-from-gson-source-copiable, no official artifacts in Maven centrals) and creating _proper_ type safe mapping. By the way, nothing is telling you're using Gson. Totally nothing. `JSONObject` comes from somewhere else and mixing libraries is usually a very bad idea. Reconsider your approach.

Comment: @terrorrussia-keeps-killing I am planning using Gson but not decided yet. That's why asked help to understand how I could do it and why I later pasted a toy code. I agree that any adapts will be very hard. Any suggestions are really welcome.